# Can I use the same Redis server with multiple magento websites, by using different Redis database numbers on each website in valet plus?

Tags: magento, magento2, valet

I am using Valet+ for my Magento projects.
I have 1 Redis server (included with Valet+ by default) and 5 different Magento projects (websites).
Can I use the same Redis server with multiple websites, by using different Redis database numbers on each website?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s possible to use 1 redis for 5 magento sites by using different database numbers per site.
I tested using 2 magento sites and it works well.
(**cache-backend-redis-db** for cache, **session-save-redis-db** for session, **page-cache-redis-db** for page cache)

If you use all, you need to use 15 database numbers (out of redis’s default 16)

Important: If you use Redis for more than one type of caching, the database numbers must be different. It is recommended that you assign the default caching database number to 0, the page caching database number to 1, and the session storage database number to 2.

**magento website-1**
`bin/magento setup:config:set --cache-backend=redis --cache-backend-redis-server=127.0.0.1 --cache-backend-redis-db=0`

`bin/magento setup:config:set --page-cache=redis --page-cache-redis-server=127.0.0.1 --page-cache-redis-db=1`

**magento website-2**
`bin/magento setup:config:set --cache-backend=redis --cache-backend-redis-server=127.0.0.1 --cache-backend-redis-db=3`

`bin/magento setup:config:set --page-cache=redis --page-cache-redis-server=127.0.0.1 --page-cache-redis-db=4 (edited)`